# Unterminated array at character

Tags: json

I m new to JSON and I'm getting this error .. Actually I'm pulling wallpapers from cloud using JSON file .. Please let me know what mistake I have done .. Please .. Blow arre the details ..

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 5995
```

this is my JSON

```
{
"wallpapers": {
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "Blur",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXF.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXFm.png",
                    "name": "Blur-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3k.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3km.png",
                    "name": "Blur-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2m.png",
                    "name": "Blur-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeo.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeom.png",
                    "name": "Blur-4"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYO.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYOm.png",
                    "name": "Blur-5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Meteor Style",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                     "url": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5m.png",
                    "name": "Avengers"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7j.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7jm.png",
                    "name": "Batman"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66v.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66vm.png",
                    "name": "C America"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42z.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42zm.png",
                    "name": "Flash"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUi.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUim.png",
                    "name": "Green Lantern"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1m.png",
                    "name": "Iron Man"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8m.png",
                    "name": "Meteor"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfS.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfSm.png",
                    "name": "Super Man"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Outer Space",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "PartimusPrime",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmh.jpg",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmhm.jpg",
                    "name": "Outer Space-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzE.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzEm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Q.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Qm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgc.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgcm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Triangulate",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpb.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpbm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3m.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8m.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgz.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgzm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-4"
                },
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoO.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoOm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-5"
                },
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQbl.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQblm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-6"
                }
            ]
        }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Any Solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: Your JSON Object has a syntax error.

Comment: Can you copy and paste correctly using the code view please you have a } outside of the code view

Comment: Just a comment every one who just provided the correct code did we all just open Notepad++ and set it to JavaScript mode and close all the "wallpaper" curly brackets until we hit a fault 

The other reason for this comment is to tell you how i & possibly every one else found and fixed the problem,

Comment: @MartinBarker I simply threw it into the JSONEditor plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors on your JSON Object near the end:

```
                }, <-- Missing new object declaractor '{'
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoO.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoOm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-5"
                }, <-- Missing new object declaractor '{'
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQbl.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQblm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-6"
                }
            ]
        }
            ] <-- Typographical error, remove this token
        }     <-- Typographical error, remove this token
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mismatched braces at the end of the json. Without line numbers etc its hard to tell you whats wrong, so here is the solution:

```
{
    "wallpapers": {
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Blur",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXF.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXFm.png",
                        "name": "Blur-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3k.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3km.png",
                        "name": "Blur-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2m.png",
                        "name": "Blur-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeo.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeom.png",
                        "name": "Blur-4"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYO.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYOm.png",
                        "name": "Blur-5"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Meteor Style",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5m.png",
                        "name": "Avengers"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7j.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7jm.png",
                        "name": "Batman"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66v.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66vm.png",
                        "name": "C America"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42z.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42zm.png",
                        "name": "Flash"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUi.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUim.png",
                        "name": "Green Lantern"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1m.png",
                        "name": "Iron Man"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8m.png",
                        "name": "Meteor"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfS.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfSm.png",
                        "name": "Super Man"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Outer Space",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "PartimusPrime",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmh.jpg",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmhm.jpg",
                        "name": "Outer Space-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzE.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzEm.png",
                        "name": "Outer Space-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Q.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Qm.png",
                        "name": "Outer Space-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgc.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgcm.png",
                        "name": "Outer Space-4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Triangulate",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpb.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpbm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3m.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8m.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgz.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgzm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-4"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoO.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoOm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-5"
                    },{
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQbl.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQblm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-6"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
     }

}
```

Please consider a decent ide/code editor that has syntax highlighting - the problem is obvious then

Answer (score 2):

Zavg got one part correct you have that incorrect, however the error you are gettins is that the last to wallpaper value for the last category are missing the object opener `{`
This is how it should be

```
{
"wallpapers": {
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "Blur",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXF.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXFm.png",
                    "name": "Blur-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3k.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3km.png",
                    "name": "Blur-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2m.png",
                    "name": "Blur-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeo.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeom.png",
                    "name": "Blur-4"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYO.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/lEuPZYOm.png",
                    "name": "Blur-5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Meteor Style",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                     "url": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5m.png",
                    "name": "Avengers"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7j.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/QCp7W7jm.png",
                    "name": "Batman"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66v.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/plaD66vm.png",
                    "name": "C America"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42z.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/hAfX42zm.png",
                    "name": "Flash"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUi.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/MQaAGUim.png",
                    "name": "Green Lantern"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1m.png",
                    "name": "Iron Man"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8m.png",
                    "name": "Meteor"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfS.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/icM5MfSm.png",
                    "name": "Super Man"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Outer Space",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "PartimusPrime",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmh.jpg",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/6DFACmhm.jpg",
                    "name": "Outer Space-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzE.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/RCMXDzEm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Q.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Qm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "edisile",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgc.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/BjwtOgcm.png",
                    "name": "Outer Space-4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Triangulate",
            "wallpaper": [
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpb.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/rxhJBpbm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-1"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/XfN47N3m.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-2"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8m.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-3"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgz.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/u1FLHgzm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-4"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoO.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/q1vAuoOm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-5"
                },
                {
                    "author": "Musaddiq",
                    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQbl.png",
                    "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/1IOAQblm.png",
                    "name": "Triangulate-6"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice, but this appears to be a duplicate of [my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652297/unterminated-array-at-character/24652431#24652431)

Comment: Apparently we got a storm of answer as we all clicked submit as i submitted this and there was like 5 answer just dropped in at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    {
    "wallpapers": {
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Blur",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXF.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/Zq3oJXFm.png",
                        "name": "Blur-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3k.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/Dri3Q3km.png",
                        "name": "Blur-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/HQLf2B2m.png",
                        "name": "Blur-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeo.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/kk4Dbeom.png",
                        "name": "Blur-4"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/lEuPZYO.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/lEuPZYOm.png",
                        "name": "Blur-5"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "MeteorStyle",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                         "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/tRkX4P5m.png",
                        "name": "Avengers"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/QCp7W7j.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/QCp7W7jm.png",
                        "name": "Batman"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/plaD66v.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/plaD66vm.png",
                        "name": "CAmerica"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/hAfX42z.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/hAfX42zm.png",
                        "name": "Flash"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/MQaAGUi.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/MQaAGUim.png",
                        "name": "GreenLantern"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/x1GBhD1m.png",
                        "name": "IronMan"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/LCSmsc8m.png",
                        "name": "Meteor"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/icM5MfS.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/icM5MfSm.png",
                        "name": "SuperMan"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "OuterSpace",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "PartimusPrime",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/6DFACmh.jpg",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/6DFACmhm.jpg",
                        "name": "OuterSpace-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/RCMXDzE.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/RCMXDzEm.png",
                        "name": "OuterSpace-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Q.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/CvXSj5Qm.png",
                        "name": "OuterSpace-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "edisile",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/BjwtOgc.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/BjwtOgcm.png",
                        "name": "OuterSpace-4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Triangulate",
                "wallpaper": [
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/rxhJBpb.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/rxhJBpbm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/XfN47N3.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/XfN47N3m.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/FQrOMK8m.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-3"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/u1FLHgz.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/u1FLHgzm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-4"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/q1vAuoO.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/q1vAuoOm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-5"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "Musaddiq",
                        "url": "http: //i.imgur.com/1IOAQbl.png",
                        "thumbUrl": "http: //i.imgur.com/1IOAQblm.png",
                        "name": "Triangulate-6"
                    }
                ]
            }

          ]
    }
 }
```

You were missing a few opening brackets and also the order was incorrect near the bottom.

You can use both [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) for help with formatting.

Comment: SO is a place to help people know what went wrong your answer just give him the fix it would be nice if you said what was wrong so the OP could learn how to fix the error on there own... (hence the Down Vote correct it and i will remove it)

Comment: Add to the above comment: The last bits of your code are formatted strangely. Try to preserve code as from the syntax by the OP and condense lines where necessary; it helps comparing what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra closing bracket and curly bracket in the end

Comment: Other answers has addressed this. Also it's too simple and could be reworded to help future readers, so please do so.

Comment: Nevertheless it is the reason why he gets the error. And its too obvious where it is once you look for it. Whatever...